# Jquery - how to send a parameter with submit()

Tags: jquery

I have a view that lists a number of companies, and a details view for each company.
When I am looking at the details of one company, I want to click on navigation buttons to see the next or previous company. Also I would like to have the first and last company as well.
So in my MVC application I am storing the Id of the first, previous, next and last company, and when the user clicks on the button, say for the next company, I want to take the next companyId and post it to the server. One way to do this is to use jquery submit(). However I cannot work out how to send the companyId in the url for submit().

So my HTML looks like;

```
<span style="margin-left:200px;">
    <input type="submit" id="btnFirst" value="|<< First"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnPrev" style="margin-right: 50px;" value="|< Previous"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnNext" value="Next >|"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnLast" value="Last >>|"/>
</span>
```

The hidden fields (converted in the page source from the MVC markup);

```
        <input id="Navigator_FirstPageId" name="Navigator.FirstPageId" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input id="Navigator_PreviousPageId" name="Navigator.PreviousPageId" type="hidden" value="7008" />
        <input id="Navigator_NextPageId" name="Navigator.NextPageId" type="hidden" value="7009" />
        <input id="Navigator_LastPageId" name="Navigator.LastPageId" type="hidden" value="7009" />
        <input id="Navigator_OnFirstPage" name="Navigator.OnFirstPage" type="hidden" value="False" />
        <input id="Navigator_OnLastPage" name="Navigator.OnLastPage" type="hidden" value="True" />
```

and the jquery that needs to be corrected;

```
$('#btnNextt').click(function () {
          submit($('#Navigator_LastPageId').val());
}
```

Comment: And what does the submit function does? Or you meant `$.submit()` ? either way consider the given hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of what I was trying to do, there was a much simpler answer;

```
<a class="imagelink" href="@Url.Action("DetailsSubcontractor", "Company", new { id = Model.Navigator.FirstPageId })">
    <input id="btnFirst" type="button" value="|<< First" />
</a>
<span style="margin-right:150px;">
<a class="imagelink" href="@Url.Action("DetailsSubcontractor", "Company", new { id = Model.Navigator.PreviousPageId })">
    <input id="btnPrev" type="button" value="|< Previous" />
</a></span>
<a class="imagelink" href="@Url.Action("DetailsSubcontractor", "Company", new { id = Model.Navigator.NextPageId })">
    <input id="btnNext" type="button" value="Next >|" />
</a>
<a class="imagelink" href="@Url.Action("DetailsSubcontractor", "Company", new { id = Model.Navigator.LastPageId })">
    <input id="btnLast" type="button" value="Last >>|" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to serialize the form on submission.

```
<form action='/some' id="myform">
       <input id="Navigator_FirstPageId" name="Navigator.FirstPageId" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input id="Navigator_PreviousPageId" name="Navigator.PreviousPageId" type="hidden" value="7008" />
        <input id="Navigator_NextPageId" name="Navigator.NextPageId" type="hidden" value="7009" />
        <input id="Navigator_LastPageId" name="Navigator.LastPageId" type="hidden" value="7009" />
        <input id="Navigator_OnFirstPage" name="Navigator.OnFirstPage" type="hidden" value="False" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$.post($('#myform').attr('action'), $('#theform').serialize());
```

Related: [jquery-ajax-submit-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)